# MS Access Updating "Completion Percent Table" by searching for values from "Table1","Table 2", "Table3" VBA Code so dont have to manually update

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to create a completion list for what tables have been completed so that I can show how far along in the project I am. I need some help on VBA code to find NULL cells so that if "PartNumber" has all null cells in the field, the corresponding part number in the "completion" table will show up as "N" for no not complete.
I am new to VBA and access and do not have much prior knowledge in VBA or coding alltogether. I have several different tables that have fields such as "FacilityManufacturedAt","TimePartCreated", "RouterNumber" and "PartNumber". The "PartNumber" field is the only field shared with the completion table and therefore I feel that it would in some way need a relationship there.
I did try for a while creating a when case for the SQL script in Access but came to findout that MS Access queries do not allow When case statements.
Thanks for any help or tips for getting this done.

Comment: Have a read of [ask] and [mcve] and then reword your original [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76122964/ms-access-updating-completion-percent-table-by-searching-for-values-from-tabl) to get it reopened.  Pictures of your tables and the code you've already tried really helps.

Comment: MS Access has the IIF function which is essentially the same as CASE WHEN - try posting the SQL you tried as well as following the instructions in Darren's comment above